# Accessing docker application running on wsl2

Tags: linux, windows, docker, airflow, wsl-2

I've setup a docker compose file using this tutorial from the [airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html) inside WSL2. The containers are healthy and apparently running fine, but I can't access them from my web browser running on Windows. I have tried several approaches, using localhost/127.0.0.1, but none of them worked. The ports are all correct, but I don't know what's going on. If I run airflow locally on wsl2, without using docker, I can access the webserver fine, but when I use docker the same method does not work anymore.